# erasing elements from a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

I'm trying to erase some old data from a 3D vector, using `iterator`. Here is a piece of my code, related to this:

```
vector< vector<vector <int> > > vol;
vector< vector< vector<int> > >::iterator row;
vector< vector<int> >::iterator col;
vector<int>::iterator dep;

for (row = this->vol.begin(); row != this->vol.end(); ++row)
{
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col)
    {
        for (dep = col->begin(); dep != col->end(); ++dep)
        {
        if ( *dep <= date - 10) {

            dep = this->vol.erase( dep );
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the compiler error :

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >::erase(std::vector<int>::iterator&)’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call erase on `vol` which to overal container.  What you need to do is call erase on the vector that `dep` belongs to.  Since `dep` points to an element of the vector that is pointed to by `col` what you need is

```
if ( *dep <= date - 10) {
    dep = col->erase( dep );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. What if I need to delete all of the elements in the third dimension instead of one?

Comment: @em.ech If you want the entire vector that `col` represents cleared then you just need `col->clear();`.

Answer (score 0):

`vol` is a `vector< vector<vector <int> > >` while `dep` is an iterator on a `vector<int>`. Only an iterator on `vector< vector<vector <int> > >` can be used as parameter for `vol->erase`.

Moreover, you can't erase items from a vector using a for loop as you wrote it. `while` loop should be preferred as iterator should only be incremented if not item were erased.

Answer (score 0):

`dep` is an iterator to an element within one of the innermost vector elements, and you are trying to use it to erase elements from the outermost vector.

Try:

```
dep = col->erase(dep);
```